# Link Component deosn't redirect page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, algolia

I am using algolia search and im rendering my hits as followes

```
function Hit(props) {
  return (
    <div>
     <Link to={'/users/'+props.hit.userName} >
      <div className="hit-name">
        <p>{props.hit.userName}</p>
        <Highlight attribute="name" hit={props.hit} />
      </div>
      <div className="hit-description">
        <Highlight attribute="description" hit={props.hit} />
      </div>
     </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**My problem:**

The Link component does not redirect the page when i click on one of the hits although when i view the rendered hits from the developer tools it is there.

**Edit 1:**

I dont want to re-render all the components i just want to render certain components in my page.I want Link to do its job not to redirect the entire page(sorry for the conflict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Link` is not meant to be anchor tag that redirects the page. It is used to link to other component pages using react router

```
function Hit(props) {
  return (
    <div>
     <a href={'/users/'+props.hit.userName}>
      <div className="hit-name">
        <p>{props.hit.userName}</p>
        <Highlight attribute="name" hit={props.hit} />
      </div>
      <div className="hit-description">
        <Highlight attribute="description" hit={props.hit} />
      </div>
     </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate away from your App, you should use a regular `<a>` React element. If you wish to redirect user to some other route inside your App, you can use `<Redirect to="" />` component from 'react-router-dom'.